# Hardwiring from a conduit above cabinet vs an outlet

Tags: electrical

I want to install a range hood that came with basic wires for hardwiring.  ant to decide between:

1. An existing junction box at the top of the cabinets OR
2. connect the wires to 16/3 and then to an outlet

I assume (1) needs me to drill holes to pass through the cabinets and (2) leaves visible wires. Any suggestions especially to be within code and easy to install.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the outlet you’d plug the cord into? (And I assume a 16awg appliance cord is the one the manufacturer specifies.)

Comment: Outlet is a foot above ground behind the range.  so the ire ill be visible from hood to the outlet.  Thanks

Comment: Please post a picture or so

Comment: Unless there's an obscure exception, I can't see how NEC would allow a standard 15A outlet to be installed into #16 wiring. If that were installed inside a product and then tested/approved by a NRTL then sure, but not as a consumer add-on.

Comment: #16 wiring shouldn’t exist on a household 120/240V AC circuit, period.

Comment: Why would you have 16/3 anyway?  What's the extra wire used for?

Answer (score 2):

Cord/plug (option 2) isn't hardwired. So if you want hardwired, which I recommend, then option 1 is the proper choice. Drilling the holes should not be hard to do.

Comment: I imagine the 16/3 wire/plug is supplied by the maker.  Would OP need to change to 14/3 or 12/3 if hardwired?  I imagine so.

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the solution.  To clarify, does the wire through the cabinet need to be metal conduit or can it be the romex ?